# Roman and arabic numerals simultaneously in Beamer appearing in top bar of Acrobat Reader

Tags: beamer

The majority of the books in pdf have roman numerals (i, ii, iii,... ) in the beginning (e.g. in the table of contends, preface,...) and these roman numerals appear in the top bar of Acrobat Reader (near the arrows to change page); the book starts only with arabic numerals (1, 2, 3,...) and also these numbers appear in the top bar of Acrobat Reader. How can I replicate this in Beamer slides? With thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a base document (`beamer` presentation) we can work with? It should include some content plus the slides you want to show with roman numerals.